# Remove leading characters and last characters of files

Tags: bash

So I had a set of files starting with numbers, and I was trying to remove them and ended up with this

```
03 - Ultimate Spider-Man #130.cbz-}
03 - Ultimate Spider-Man #156.cbz-}
03 - Ultimate Spider-Man #76-77.cbz-}
04 - Ultimate Spider-Man #157.cbz-}
04 - Ultimate Spider-Man #78.cbz-}
```

Any clue on a bash script on how to remove the '-}' and the leading numbers? so the output'd be

```
Ultimate Spider-Man #130.cbz
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the contents of the file or the names of files you want to rename?

Comment: If they're filenames, use the `rename` command to rename them using regexp replacement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should check out `man bash` under heading `EXPANSION`

If all file names start with the same number of characters, you could do something like this:

```
LIST=$(ls) #you can make a list of all the file names and store in a variable
for i in $LIST; do
    mv $i ${i:4}
done
```

This would then "replace" out the first four characters and white spaces.

So if you had `03 - foo bar` you would get `foo bar`.

Or if you do `mv $i ${i:4:4}` you would get `foo`.

Just an idea of how it could be done. You can play around with that.